# BindRequired in another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this situation on the properties in the Model:

```
[BindRequired]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

I'm doing a modular API and the Model goes to another Assembly

The new Assembly does not have access to `AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding`

This causes that I can not use the attribute `[BindRequired]`

What to do in this situation?

**EDIT:**

- String defaults to NULL

Is `[BindRequired]` necessary for this value?

Is `[BindRequired]` the equivalent of a value like this:

```
public int? MyValue{ get; set; }
```

vs

```
[BindRequired]
public int MyValue{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Assuming that the other assembly will process the posted data, I still think you should validate it before pass it on. It will most likely be much simpler to deal with invalid data at the first instance, where you use `[BindRequired]`, and take advantage of built-in features.

Comment: It tells you, that you need to change the design and did not properly abstract/encapsulate your modules. Your (domain) models shouldn't depend on infrastructure. It usually happens when you try to use domain models or persistence models as DTOs/ViewModels (response of WebAPI calls)

Answer (score 0):

For using `BindRequired`, you need to add reference `AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding`. For modular, you could try the suggestion from @Tseng to redesign your project with Entity and ViewModel. We should not use present layer in domain models.

> Is [BindRequired] necessary for this value?

In short answer, it is. `[BindRequired]` causes model binding to add a model state error if binding cannot occur for a model's property.

If you did not pass `Gender` while submitting form, you will get model state error even through it could be null.

For non-null properties like int,

```
[BindRequired]
public int MyValue{ get; set; }
```

Are equal to

```
[Required]
public int? MyValue{ get; set; }
```